# angular 2 FlashMessages cssClass not working

Tags: angular

my register.ts

```
onRegisterSubmit()
  {
    const user ={
      firstname: this.firstname,
      lastname:this.lastname,
      email: this.email,
      password:this.password
    }
    //required fields
    if(!this._validateService.validateRegister(user)){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please fill in all fields',{cssClass:'alert-danger',timeout:3000});
      return false;
    }
}
```

this flashMessage function is working properly,but that message not visible. i think i did mistake in cssClass. i can't find why this message not visible in my page. please help me if anyone know

Comment: Create an example on stackblitz.com reproducing the issue. As is, it's hard to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way -

```
 this.flashMessage.success('Message', {
        dalay: 2000, <number>
        generalClass: 'success-class', <strigng>
        close: true, <boolean>
        closeBtnClass: 'class1 class2', <string>
        navigate: 'you-url', <string>
 });
```